# Determine installation directory of SQL Server Instance on 64bit machine from 32bit .NET app

Tags: c#, registry, sql-server-2008-r2, 32bit-64bit

I was trying to determine the installation directory of a SQL Server instance on a 64 bit machine from a 32bit .NET app, and got caught for a while trying to get the registry to work correctly as the regular registry accessed by my code was being virtualized or whatnot by the Windows OS.

I think I have an answer, but I was wondering if there was a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't finish checking my first answer's correctness because there is a somewhat better way, which is to use the WMI as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5497319/832705

Answer (score 0):

Write a small 64-bit program that does the trick and call the .exe from your 32-bit application.

Answer (score -1):

My solution is to ask SQLServer what the registry has for it's install directory because it is a 64bit app and can get to the regular 64bit registry and isn't stuck in the 32bit registry sandbox or notwhat.

That can be done using this fellow's answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/533592/832705

Really great, thanks kindly, Mr. Ian

Comment: Its going to be one of two places, both are known to you, only one exists on a x64 operating system.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned the server is a Named Instance, and might be running from an instance specific installation directory.